# Spring-boot application.properties not recognized in gradle project

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I created a spring boot project based on gradle and write `server.port=8180` in  application.properties.

Then i run this project, it doesn't work, port is still 8080.

I do the same thing in a maven project, then run it, it works!

Why?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q5My.png)

I run two projects like the image.

Comment: Could you show the gradle project structure? Make sure you run the gradle project with "gradlew bootRun"

Comment: Show us how you run the project both in maven and in gradle.